# Search Active Directory for all matching objects

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, directoryservices

- **Goal:** I would like to query AD for both users and computer objects using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace. (Example: Search for the keyword "Test", and i will get back user accounts and computer accounts containing "Test")
- Currently I use the two methods below to achieve this. If it's possible, i would like to combine both these methods into a single. I've tried playing around with the `AdvancedFilters` class but no success =(
- Another Example of what I'm looking for: In PowerShell using the AD module, I'm able to use a command like this `Get-ADObject -Filter 'SamAccountName -like "*test*"'` to do exactly what i need.

Query Computers:

```
    public PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> GetADComputer(string pcName)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);            
        ComputerPrincipal computer = new ComputerPrincipal(ctx);
        computer.Name = String.Format("*{0}*", pcName);

        PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
        searcher.QueryFilter = computer;

        return searcher.FindAll();
    }
```

Query Users

```
    public PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> GetADUser(string userName)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
        user.SamAccountName = String.Format("*{0}*", userName);

        PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
        searcher.QueryFilter = user;

        return searcher.FindAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about AccountManagement, but I would achieve that using DirectoryServices :

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myldapserver.com");
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(|(objectclass=user)(objectclass=computer))(samaccountname=*"+objectName+"*))";
SearchResultCollection srCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm really trying to keep all my AD related code to the AccountManagement class. If i can't find any other way i will resort to this code.